# google finance api alternative for monitoring/modifying portfolio?

Tags: api, finance, google-finance, google-finance-api

I used to use google finance to create portfolios/change them and then display them on my site but since its being removed I'm wondering if there's any good free alternatives?

Basically I have a program that creates different portfolios based on different factors(20 right now), so each of the 20 links on my site direct people to a page that displays the portfolios. I am looking for something that I can use to automatically update the portfolios.

If it helps, my site is basically a free tutorial site that helps people learn how to manage their own portfolios. There's different lessons and then using market data & news(which I already get) I automatically generate a sample portfolio to show them how everything comes together. I liked google finance because they could see all of google's data but they could also click around and dig deeper if they want.

Is there anything I can use to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but it sounds like @DirkEddelbuettel's [BeanCounter](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/beancounter.html) will do what you need.

Or, if you're just looking for quotes see http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm and http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/